# Hide/Remove DIV With Whitespaces

Tags: removing-whitespace

here's the issue I'm having. I want to hide or remove the div that is empty or have white spaces. If you open the below link in Firefox and do firebug, you will still see those empty divs. How can I remove or hide them?

http://jsfiddle.net/f5BMy/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.row').each(function(index) {
         if($(this).text().trim() == '') {
               $(this).remove();
               // or $(this).hide();
          }
        });
    });​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f5BMy/3/